# Can't change customers groupId in observer

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, event-observer, sales-order, customer-group

I try to change the customers group id in the observer `sales_order_place_after` but it seems to be impossible. I successfully managed to change the firstname of the customer just for test, but groupId ? No chance...

Can someone explain why it is not possible to change the groupId ?

This is my attempt:

```
class EaDesign_CustomerGroup_Model_SalesOrderPlaceAfterObserver
{
    ...

    public function changeCustomerGroup(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {    
        try
        {
            $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
            $newGroupId = '7';

            $customer->setGroupId($newGroupId);  // does not work
            //$customer->setData('group_id', $newGroupId);  // second attempt, not working too


                    $customer->setFirstname('hans');  // this works

                    $customer->save();
                    if ($customer->save())
                    {
                        Mage::Log('customer saved', 7, 'autochange_customer_group.log', true);  // this is logged
                    }


        } catch (Exception $e) {

            Mage::log('customer session moving ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

But the customer group is still the same!

I made sure that the customer group id is correct by inspecting the HTML code in the backend:

[image]

Comment: Customer is saved twice, remove this one $customer->save(); before the if and try. 
as well as print $customer->getData() and $customer->getOrigData()  before and after save, which gives you an idea, why its not set.

Comment: I removed the second save, but it still fails. I placed getOrigData before and after and there was no change in the groupId. getData shows the new ID. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that it is working with the same code in another magento installation where the same git branch is checked out. So it was clear that the error was caused by difference in the database, or in other words: by magento settings.

So I compared the settings from both installations and after alot of comparing I found out that it was due to the setting in (following is translated from german...) `System -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customerconfiguration -> Create Customer Options -> Activate automatic customer group`. After setting the value to `No` it suddenly works.